# How to count tuples containing the same value?

Tags: mysql, relational-database, relational-algebra

Suppose these are the columns:

```
 **name**     **course**
   andy          bio         
   brian         math
   andy          chem
```

How can I count the name "andy" appeared twice?

Comment: **Moderator Note:** Lack of Research Effort is not a valid close reason.  Find a valid reason to close, or downvote instead.

Comment: I'm sure the answer would include the `COUNT()` function and the `WHERE` clause comparing the `**name**` columns with certain value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use group by and count by name

Something like:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) FROM my_table GROUP BY name
```

Here's a SQLFiddle to demonstrate: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/966da/1

Comment: Use your shift key, folks.

Comment: Was it really such an egregious error that I forgot to capitalize one word?